# java.lang.IllegalStateException when using State in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack-compose

I have `ViewModel` with Kotlin sealed class to provide different states for UI. Also, I use `androidx.compose.runtime.State` object to notify UI about changes in state.

If error on `MyApi` request occurs, I put `UIState.Failure` to `MutableState` object and then I get `IllegalStateException`:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reading a state that was created after the snapshot was taken or in a snapshot that has not yet been applied
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotKt.readError(Snapshot.kt:1524)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotKt.current(Snapshot.kt:1764)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotMutableStateImpl.setValue(SnapshotState.kt:797)
        at com.vladuken.compose.ui.category.CategoryListViewModel$1.invokeSuspend(CategoryListViewModel.kt:39)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:104)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:738)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

ViemModel code:

```
@HiltViewModel
class CategoryListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val api: MyApi
) : ViewModel() {

    sealed class UIState {
        object Loading : UIState()
        data class Success(val categoryList: List<Category>) : UIState()
        object Error : UIState()
    }

    val categoryListState: State<UIState>
        get() = _categoryListState
    private val _categoryListState =
        mutableStateOf<UIState>(UIState.Loading)

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val categories = api
                    .getCategory().schemas
                    .map { it.toDomain() }
                _categoryListState.value = UIState.Success(categories)

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                //this does not work
                _categoryListState.value = UIState.Error
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I tried to delay setting UIState.Error - and it worked, but I don't think it is normal solution:

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val categories = api
                    .getCategory().schemas
                    .map { it.toDomain() }
                _categoryListState.value = UIState.Success(categories)

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                //This works 
                delay(10)
                _categoryListState.value = UIState.Error
            }
        }
```

I observe State object in Composable function as follows:

```
@Composable
fun CategoryScreen(
    viewModel: CategoryListViewModel,
    onCategoryClicked: (Category) -> Unit
) {
    when (val uiState = viewModel.categoryListState.value) {
        is CategoryListViewModel.UIState.Error -> CategoryError()
        is CategoryListViewModel.UIState.Loading -> CategoryLoading()
        is CategoryListViewModel.UIState.Success -> CategoryList(
            categories = uiState.categoryList,
            onCategoryClicked
        )
    }
}
```

Compose Version : `1.0.0-beta03`

How to process sealed class `UIState` with Compose `State` so that it doesn't throw IllegalStateException?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, after more attempts of fixing this issue I found a solution.
With help of https://stackoverflow.com/a/66892156/13101450 answer I've get that snapshots are transactional and run on ui thread - changing dispatcher helped:

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val categories = api
                    .getCategory().schemas
                    .map { it.toDomain() }
                _categoryListState.value = UIState.Success(categories)

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    _categoryListState.value = UIState.Error
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: dont use try catch use flow{ }.catch{}

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get the following error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reading a state that was created after the snapshot was taken or in a snapshot that has not yet been applied`

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 50):

Three ways this can be resolved are

- 1. To call the method in a launched effect block in your composable
- 2. Or set the Context to Dispatchers.Main when setting value of the mutableState using withContext(Dispatchers.Main)
- 3. Or change the mutable state in viewModel to mutableState flow and use collectAsState() in composable to collect it as a state.

Comment: Very concise and accurate.

Comment: The third option is more suitable if you need to use Dispachers.IO like database operations. Accurate answer.

Comment: Great answer @Neo can you explain the reason ?

Comment: 2 - so `State` is not thread safe when setting value from non-Main thread?

Answer (score 17):

There's a discussion about what looks like somewhat similar issue in https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1613581738163700.

Some relevant parts of that discussion I think (from Adam Powell)

> As for the thread-safety aspects of snapshot state, what you've
> encountered is the result of snapshots being transactional.
>
> When a snapshot is taken (and composition does this for you under the
> hood) the currently active snapshot is thread-local. Everything that
> happens in composition is part of this transaction, and that
> transaction hasn't committed yet.
>
> So when you create a new mutableStateOf in composition and then pass
> it to another thread, as the GlobalScope.launch in the problem snippet
> does, you've essentially let a reference to snapshot state that
> doesn't exist yet escape from the transaction.

The exact scenario is a little different here but I think same key issue.  Probably wouldn't do it exactly this way but at least here it worked by moving contents of `init` in to new `getCategories()` method which is then called from `LaunchedEffect` block.  FWIW what I've done elsewhere in case like this (while still invoking in `init`) is using `StateFlow` in view model and then call `collectAsState()` in Compose code.

```
@Composable
fun CategoryScreen(
    viewModel: CategoryListViewModel,
    onCategoryClicked: (Category) -> Unit
) {
    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        viewModel.getCategories()
    }

    when (val uiState = viewModel.categoryListState.value) {
        is CategoryListViewModel.UIState.Error -> CategoryError()
        is CategoryListViewModel.UIState.Loading -> CategoryLoading()
        is CategoryListViewModel.UIState.Success -> CategoryList(
            categories = uiState.categoryList,
            onCategoryClicked
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hate to say this but `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` didn't worked for me. So I called the init method from `LaunchedEffect` from composable which works as expected.

```
class VideosViewModel : ViewModel() {
    fun init() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            setState { copy(isLoading = true) }
            // work here
            setState { copy(isLoading = false) }
        }
    }
}
```

Composable

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
    viewModel.init()
}
```