# How To Change a State from Another Thread to force a recomposition in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have a simple `Text` Element where I want to display the current time.

I tried to start a periodically `Timer Task` but it says `APP STOPPED WORKING`. What is the correct approach to *periodically* update my `var currentTime by mutableStateOf("12:00")` inside another Thread so it forces a correct recomposition without crashing?.

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var currentTime by mutableStateOf("12:00")

    init {
        val clockTimer = Timer()
        clockTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                val hoursAndMinutes = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US).format(Date())
                Log.d("DEBUG", "Current Time is: $hoursAndMinutes")
                currentTime = hoursAndMinutes
            }
         }, 0, 60000)
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun ClockView(myViewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()){
    Text(
        text = myViewModel.currentTime
    )
}
```

## EDIT1: ADDED STACKTRACE

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
   Process: com.myapp.c, PID: 15437
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reading a state that was created after the snapshot was taken or in a snapshot that has not yet been applied
            at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotKt.readError(Snapshot.kt:1857)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotKt.current(Snapshot.kt:2110)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotMutableStateImpl.setValue(SnapshotState.kt:299)
            at com.myapp.c.ui.MyViewModel.setCurrentTime(Test.kt:41)
            at com.myapp.c.ui.MyViewModel$1.run(Test.kt:25)
            at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:562)
            at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:512)
```

Comment: You may need to use something like `Snapshot.takeMutableSnapshot()`. See https://dev.to/zachklipp/introduction-to-the-compose-snapshot-system-19cn. It would help, though, if you posted more of the stack trace, not just an error message.

Comment: I have tried using your suggestion but apparently a [Snapshot](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/compose.runtime/runtime/1.0.0-alpha04-source/androidx/compose/runtime/snapshots/Snapshot.kt.html) is only thread specific so this doesn't help me. I will read the whole blog tomorrow again to check if i missed something. Still thanks <3

Comment: `All state objects will return the values associated with this snapshot, locally in the thread [...] All other threads are unaffected.`

Comment: For the error from your edit, see https://jetc.dev/slack/2022-05-16-mutating-state-viewmodel-constructor.html

Answer (score 2):

The Snapshots are transactional, hence needed to be run on main thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66891349/java-lang-illegalstateexception-when-using-state-in-android-jetpack-compose/66892156#66892156),
And cannot be updated from another thread except `main`.
Hence to update/read the value you need to be on UI thread, i.e. main thread.

run this `currentTime = hoursAndMinutes` on main thread, by wrapping it in coroutine, like

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    currentTime = hoursAndMinutes
}
```

As `viewModelScope` is bound to `Dispatchers.Main.immediate`, it will run on main thread.

Comment: This is correct and I will use this but generally speaking this is not a real thread. Any way to manage the main snapshot from another *real* thread